# How to iterate over a sorted set?

Tags: swift, sorting, set

I'm using Xcode 6.3, and the following is the code in the book The Swift programming language:

```
var fav:Set=["cd","bsa","aft"]
for genre in fav.sort(){
   println("\(genre)")
}
```

But the compiler reported the error

> 'Set' does not has a member named 'sort'

Has Apple added `sort()` to `Set` in Xcode 6.4, or am I using it in a wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading the wrong version of the iBook if you're using Xcode 6.3. There are two versions of this book currently available.

1. [The Swift Programming Language](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11)
2. [The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2 Prerelease)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id1002622538?mt=11)

The former contains examples using Swift 1.2, which comes with Xcode 6.3, whereas the latter translates these examples to Swift 2, which requires Xcode 7.

In the case of the code you're provided, Apple provides the following example from the non-prerelease book.

```
for genre in sorted(favoriteGenres) {
    println("\(genre)")
}
```

Which uses Swift 1's global [sorted()](http://swiftdoc.org/func/sorted/) function, which (as well as the global [sort()](http://swiftdoc.org/func/sort/) function) has been removed in Swift 2. In Swift 2, both of these global functions have been replaced by [sort()](http://swiftdoc.org/swift-2/func/sort/) instance methods declared via protocol extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick comparison:

## Swift 2

```
var favoriteGenres: Set = ["Rock", "Classical", "Hip hop"]
for genre in favoriteGenres.sort() {
    print("\(genre)")
}
```

## Swift 1.2

```
var favoriteGenres: Set = ["Rock", "Classical", "Hip hop"]
for genre in sorted(favoriteGenres) {
    println("\(genre)")
}
```

See [Collection Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) for more documentation.